# How to count down time until timer's next tick?

Tags: c#, timer

I have 2 timers. One of them is counting each time it ticks; while using steady interval, or one randomly generated. Second timer counts down to next tick in first timer.

As of right now I am doing as such:

```
    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        nextClick = int.Parse(nudClickInterval.Value.ToString());

        if (nudPlusMinus.Value != 0) tmrClickInterval.Interval = random.Next( int.Parse(nudClickInterval.Value.ToString()) - int.Parse(nudPlusMinus.Value.ToString()), int.Parse(nudClickInterval.Value.ToString()) + int.Parse(nudPlusMinus.Value.ToString()));
        else tmrClickInterval.Interval = int.Parse(nudClickInterval.Value.ToString());

        tmrClickInterval.Start();
    }

    private void tmrClickInterval_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (nudPlusMinus.Value == 0) tmrClickInterval.Interval = int.Parse(nudClickInterval.Value.ToString());
        else tmrClickInterval.Interval = random.Next(int.Parse(nudClickInterval.Value.ToString()) - int.Parse(nudPlusMinus.Value.ToString()), int.Parse(nudClickInterval.Value.ToString()) + int.Parse(nudPlusMinus.Value.ToString()));

        tmrNextClick.Interval = tmrClickInterval.Interval / 10;
        tmrNextClick.Start();
        content++;
        nextClick = tmrClickInterval.Interval;
        label1.Text = content.ToString();
    }

    private void tmrNextClick_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (nextClick <= 0) tmrNextClick.Stop();
        else
        {
            nextClick = nextClick - (tmrClickInterval.Interval / 10);
            lblNextClickCount.Text = (nextClick / 100).ToString();
        }
    }
```

I am setting up an interval of my count down timer by using first timer's interval dividing by 10. The problem is that I keep getting some errors such as: `Value '0' is not a valid value for Interval. Interval must be greater than 0.` at line: `tmrNextClick.Interval = tmrClickInterval.Interval / 10;`.

I'm not sure how to avoid my errors so I figure there might be a better way of counting down time until next timer tick. Plus, I'd want a count down in nice steady interval instead but I am getting quite confused and not sure how to manage this problem.

Hope for some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.Windows.Forms.Timer` has an `int` intervall. Dividing a number which is samller than 10 by 10 results in 0 (integer division!).

Try to use `System.Timers.Timer`, it has an interval of type `double`, or check for 0 and assign 1 in that case.

Comment: Thanks for a advice to try using double version of timer's interval. Might be useful.

Comment: BTW. One quick question. What's the minimum allowed timer interval?

Comment: with System.Windows.Forms.Timer its 1, for System.Timers.Timer this guy says its 1 / 64 sec http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/ask-dr-dotnetsky/12/61662/c--timer-interval-below-164-sec-.aspx

Comment: Microsofts documentation says that it throws an execption if "The interval is less than or equal to zero". But the minimum resolution probably depends on the specific hardware.